# Is it possible to develop an app that backup sms to gmail on WebOS 1.4.5?

Tags: sms, webos

I love my Palm Pixi Plus(webos 1.4.5),
and I'm a sms hard user,
I searched so long time but find nothing,
Is it so hard or just impossible?
If webos 1.4.5 can't do it,will 2.0+ ?
I can't believe nobody need such an important function,
Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Anything is possible. It looks like you have an application idea in your hands. Build it before someone else does.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this actually is not possible without writing a patch for the messaging app, and for good reason. It's not possible (at least, not documented) for an app to read the user's messages (which would be a large security flaw). However, it should definitely be possible to write a patch for messaging that performs some action upon receiving / sending a message.